# How to assign a DB value to a PHP variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to assign a DB value to a PHP variable. The database is SQL. I want the database value to be $HaveOfficialPage. How can I do this?

```
 $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', '');

    if($connection){

        echo "Connected";

    }

    else {

        die("Database connection failed");

    }

    $query = "SELECT HaveOfficialPage FROM vf_Category";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


    if(!$result){

        die("Query failed" . mysqli_error());
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what you're asking or trying to do.

Comment: @Fred-ii- , I want to assign the database value for HaveOfficialPage to a variable  which would be $HaveOfficialPage.

Comment: I don't see in your code the `$HaveOfficialPage` variable you mentioned. Where exactly is your problem? Are you getting any error even before trying to assign a value to the variable? BTW, I would say it's better using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead of mysqli.

Comment: @golds Please do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re trying to iterate through the results:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
      $haveOfficialPage = $row[0];
    // do something with the variable
}
```

If you’re getting only one record:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$haveOfficialPage = $row["HaveOfficialPage"];
```

To select a category with a condition, use prepared statements

```
$paths = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$category = end($paths);
$query = "SELECT HaveOfficialPage FROM vf_Category WHERE category_name = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $category);

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $haveOfficialPage); // here we assign the result to your variable
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt); // fetch

echo $haveOfficialPage;
```

Comment: I would like that, but not for the whole row.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you only need one result?

Comment: yes, the field for that particular category.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.

Comment: issue is that It displays the first row in the database's field for "HaveOfficialPage." I need it to display the field/row which corresponds with that category page.

Comment: Well I don't know what your table structure is. But to select a row according to a field, you use `SELECT HaveOfficialPage FROM vf_Category WHERE category_name = 'something'`. Category_name here is an example. But your question was resolved so you should mark as answered and ask a new question, to keep it organized. I'm happy to help

Comment: thanks for the response. How do I make "something" automatic. So, it sees url root and puts that as the "something." Can you update your answer to reflect this and the code above you provided.

Comment: I will. But it will be unclear to anyone who reads it in the future, so next time try to ask a new question :)

Comment: thanks please let me know once you do so I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: I need it to get the url from the page it's for, not from a form. Can you please update to reflect that.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Simply change $category to be whatever you want it to be.

Comment: can I get a certain part of the page url (http://www.website.com/GETTHISPARTONLY)?

Comment: Yes, with $_SEVER["REQUEST_URI"]. I've updated. Please ask another question.